# Python Requirements para AWS Lambda

Tags: python

Actualmente tengo una API que se ejecuta en Heroku, quiero moverla a AWS Lambda pero quiero saber si es posible usar el mismo stack que ya uso en Heroku.

La API esta desarrollada en Python con FastApi

En el `requirements.txt` tengo

```
pandas==1.3.5
openpyxl==3.0.10
requests==2.23.0
bs4==0.0.1
uvicorn==0.19.0
fastapi==0.86.0
lxml==4.9.1
```

La API hace solicitudes a distintas fuentes.